# How I can make list length method in scala?

Tags: scala

I need to make function that will be returning list length (of course without standart scala method)

```
val a = 3 :: 4 :: 7 :: 9 :: Nil
var b = 0
var i = 0
def listLength[A](xs: List[A]): Int = {
if (xs(i) != null && i < xs.length)
  b += 1
  i += 1
listLength(a)
b
}
println(listLength(a))
```

For this method I have an error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Comment: "of course without standart scala method" You are using it in `i < xs.length`.

Comment: I mean that I can`t use method length to replace the function. I need to to made it)

Comment: Why to use the `var b` again. Just the `var i` can be returned at the end of the function `listLength[A](xs:List[A])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `xs(i) != null` doesn't do what you think. A `List` might contain a `null` element but it has nothing to do with the end-of-list and it should still be counted.

And this `i < xs.length` totally defeats the purpose of calculating the length of a `List` without using `.length`.

This (or something like it) is probably what you're looking for.

```
def listLength[A](xs: List[A]): Int = xs match {
  case Nil => 0
  case _ :: tail => 1 + listLength(tail)
}
```

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz You have it the wrong way round! This answer is not tail recursive because the last operation is `+` not the recursive call. The accepted answer (and my answer) *are* tail recursive.

Answer (score 1):

you can not `List.apply(notExisingIndex)` as `apply` [clearly exploding in case of non existing index](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.7/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L63).

```
  def apply(n: Int): A = {
    val rest = drop(n)
    if (n < 0 || rest.isEmpty) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("" + n)
    rest.head
  }
```

You can do `Try(List.apply(notExisingIndex))` or even better `List.lift` if you want but that might not be good approach.

**I would find the `length` using "pattern match" until the list is `Nil`.**

```
def length[a](list: List[a], l: Int = 0): Int = {
  list match {
    case head :: tail => length(tail, l + 1)
    case Nil => l
  }
}

println(length(List()))           //0
println(length(List(1)))          //1
println(length(List(1, 2)))       //2
println(length(List(1, 2, 3)))    //3
println(length(List(1, 2, 3, 4))) //4
```

Comment: glad to help. keep on fping

Answer (score 1):

I would combine the two previous answers to give this:

```
def length[T](list: List[T]) = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(list: List[T], res: Int): Int = list match {
    case Nil => res
    case head :: tail => loop(tail, res+1)
  }

  loop(list, 0)
}
```

This is tail-recursive so it compiles to a simple loop, but it doesn't have a spurious extra value in the outer function signature.